# How to add Search Bar in UITableView Like game center in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have added Search Bar to UITableView(tblViewGallery). I have added searchBar tableHeader of UITableView(tblViewGallery).Thus added Search bar is working fine UITableView(tblViewGallery). But Now I want searchBar to be displayed like as "Game Center" searchBar. I want to hide the SearchBar when tblViewGallery is first shown and when when we scroll the tblViewGallery downwards then Search Bar will be shown but it will lock the UINavigationBar like as "Game Center" searchBar. What approach should I follow ?? I have tried as,

```
[tblViewGallery scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

using this I,m able to hide the searchBar when firstly our tblViewGallery is displayed and when I scroll tableView Downwards the Search bar also appears but it is not locking the UINavigation Bar. For Locking I have tried below code in delegate method of UIScrollView `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

```
CGRect rect = searchBar.frame;
rect.origin.y = MIN(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
searchBar.frame = rect;
```

Comment: What is the exact problem that you're having? What does "it is not locking the UINavigationBar" mean?

Comment: yes, it is not locking the UINavigationBar like Game Center and also SearchBar is hiding automatically when I put any letter or character to search.

Comment: @Stonz2, how to lock the search bar below navigation bar.....

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're going to have to be more specific, as I still have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to add searchBar like "Game Center" of iPhone.....

Answer (score 1):

If what I think you're trying todo is correct you want the search bar to scroll out of view as the user scrolls down, and allow the table headers to lock to the top of the navigation bar.

Based on that what I would do is first set your `UITableView` style to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. Then override the `viewForHeaderInSection` method to provide a header for each group. The header would be a simple UIView with some text.

Then for the first row instead of loading your normal cell you'd load a `UITableViewCell` subclass with a `UISearchBar` in it. Then in your 'viewForHeaderInSection' return a `UIView` subclass with a height of zero for the first group.

This would give you a UISearchBar at the top of your `UITabeView`, it would NOT have a header, it would scroll out of the view as the user scrolls down, and the other headers will lock to the `UINavigationBar` when scroll as that is the default behavior.

Does that help?